# Apache Tomcat7 Memory leaks (Suspecting a singleton object)

Tags: java, tomcat7, java-web-start

I am currently developing a Java Web application on a machine with the
following
attributes:

- Ubuntu-Server Edition Linux 12.04 64-bit
- Sun java JDK version 7
- Apache Tomcat 7.0.30
- Netbeans IDE, version 7.1.2

My project consists of a SOAP Web service interface, that maintains a
shared in-
memory object. In order to make the object visible to all threads, I
developed a
Singleton. I post the code of my application below:

```
@WebService()
public class ETL_WS {

    private Singleton CAP_offer_coupon_map;

    public ETL_WS() { }

    /**
     * This method adds a single coupon record to the memory map.
     */
    @WebMethod
    synchronized public int singleCouponLoad(@WebParam(name =
            "CouponID") long coupon_id,
            @WebParam(name = "ProductCategoryID") long product_category_id,
            @WebParam(name = "DateTo") Date dateTo,
            @WebParam(name = "LocationID") Location location_id) {
        Coupon _c = new Coupon(coupon_id, product_category_id, dateTo);
        if(location_id != null)
            _c.setLocation(location_id);
        CAP_CouponOfferCollection _data = CAP_offer_coupon_map.getModel();
        Coupon _tmp = _data.getCoupon(coupon_id);
        if(_tmp == null)
            return -1;
        _data.insertCoupon(_c);
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * This method adds a single offer record to the memory map.
     */
    @WebMethod
    synchronized public int singleOfferLoad(@WebParam(name =
            "OfferID") long offer_id,
            @WebParam(name = "ProductCategoryID") long product_category_id,
            @WebParam(name = "DateTo") Date dateTo,
            @WebParam(name = "LocationID") Location location_id) {
        Offer _o = new Offer(offer_id, product_category_id, dateTo);
        if(location_id != null)
            _o.setLocation(location_id);
        CAP_CouponOfferCollection _data = CAP_offer_coupon_map.getModel();
        Offer _tmp = _data.getOffer(offer_id);
        if(_tmp == null)
            return -1;
        _data.insertOffer(_o);
        return 0;
    }

    @WebMethod
    synchronized public String getAllCoupons() {
        CAP_CouponOfferCollection _data = CAP_offer_coupon_map.getModel();
        HashMap<Long, Coupon> _c = _data.getCoupons_map();
        return _c.toString();
    }

    @WebMethod
    synchronized public String getAllOffers() {
        CAP_CouponOfferCollection _data = CAP_offer_coupon_map.getModel();
        HashMap<Long, Offer> _o = _data.getOffers_map();
        return _o.toString();
    }

    @WebMethod
    synchronized public long getProductIdFromCouponId(@**WebParam(name
            = "CouponID") long coupon_id) {
        long _product_id = -1;
        CAP_CouponOfferCollection _data = CAP_offer_coupon_map.getModel();
        Coupon _c = _data.getCoupon(coupon_id);
        if(_c != null)
            _product_id = _c.getCoupon_id();
        return _product_id;
    }

    @WebMethod
    synchronized public long getProductIdFromOfferId(@WebParam(name = "OfferID") long 
            offer_id) {
        long _product_id = -1;
        CAP_CouponOfferCollection _data = CAP_offer_coupon_map.getModel();
        Offer _o = _data.getOffer(offer_id);
        if(_o != null)
            _product_id = _o.getOffer_id();
        return _product_id;
    }

}
```

The Singleton wrapper-class is shown below:

```
public class Singleton {

    private static boolean _instanceFlag = false;

    private static final Singleton _instance = new Singleton();

    private static CAP_CouponOfferCollection _data;

    private Singleton() {
    _data = new CAP_CouponOfferCollection();
    _instanceFlag = true;
    }

    public static synchronized CAP_CouponOfferCollection getModel() {
    if(_instanceFlag == false) {
        _data = new CAP_CouponOfferCollection();
        _instanceFlag = true;
    }
    return _data;
    }
}
```

and the CAP_CouponOfferCollection class is shown below:

```
public class CAP_CouponOfferCollection {

    private HashMap<Long, Coupon> _coupons_map;

    private HashMap<Long, ArrayList<Long>> _product_to_coupons_map;

    private HashMap<Long, Offer> _offers_map;

    private HashMap<Long, ArrayList<Long>> _product_cat_to_offers_map;

    private static long _creation_time;

    public CAP_CouponOfferCollection() {
        _creation_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Creation of CAP_CouponOffer object: " +
            _creation_time);
    }

    synchronized public void insertCoupon(Coupon newCoupon) {
        if(_coupons_map == null) {
            _coupons_map = new HashMap<Long, Coupon>();
            _product_to_coupons_map =
                    new HashMap<Long, ArrayList<Long>>();
        }
        Long key = newCoupon.getCoupon_id();
        if(!_coupons_map.containsKey(key)) {
            _coupons_map.put(key, newCoupon);
            key = newCoupon.getProductCategory_id();
            if(_product_to_coupons_map.containsKey(key)) {
                ArrayList<Long> _c_list = _product_to_coupons_map.get(key);
                _c_list.add(newCoupon.getCoupon_id());
                _product_to_coupons_map.remove(key);
                _product_to_coupons_map.put(key, _c_list);
            }else {
                ArrayList<Long> _c_list = new ArrayList<Long>();
                _c_list.add(newCoupon.getCoupon_id());
                _product_to_coupons_map.put(key, _c_list);
            }
        }
    }

    synchronized public void insertOffer(Offer newOffer) {
        if(_offers_map == null) {
            _offers_map = new HashMap<Long, Offer>();
            _product_cat_to_offers_map =
                    new HashMap<Long, ArrayList<Long>>();
        }
        Long key = newOffer.getOffer_id();
        if(!_offers_map.containsKey(key)) {
            _offers_map.put(key, newOffer);
            key = newOffer.getProductCategory_id();
            if(_product_cat_to_offers_map.containsKey(key)) {
                ArrayList<Long> _o_list = _product_cat_to_offers_map.get(key);
                _o_list.add(newOffer.getOffer_id());
                _product_cat_to_offers_map.remove(key);
                _product_cat_to_offers_map.put(key, _o_list);
            }else {
                ArrayList<Long> _o_list = new ArrayList<Long>();
                _o_list.add(newOffer.getOffer_id());
                _product_cat_to_offers_map.put(key, _o_list);
            }
        }
    }

    synchronized public void removeCoupon(long couponId) {
        Coupon _c;
        Long key = new Long(couponId);
        if(_coupons_map != null && _coupons_map.containsKey(key)) {
            _c = (Coupon) _coupons_map.get(key);
            _coupons_map.remove(key);
            Long product = new Long(_c.getCoupon_id());
            ArrayList<Long> _c_list =
                    (ArrayList<Long>) _product_to_coupons_map.get(product);
            _c_list.remove(key);
            _product_to_coupons_map.remove(product);
            _product_to_coupons_map.put(product, _c_list);
        }
    }

    synchronized public void removeOffer(long offerId) {
        Offer _o;
        Long key = new Long(offerId);
        if(_offers_map != null && _offers_map.containsKey(key)) {
            _o = (Offer) _offers_map.get(key);
            _offers_map.remove(key);
            Long product = new Long(_o.getOffer_id());
            ArrayList<Long> _o_list =
                    (ArrayList<Long>) _product_cat_to_offers_map.get(product);
            _o_list.remove(key);
            _product_cat_to_offers_map.remove(product);
            _product_cat_to_offers_map.put(product, _o_list);
        }
    }

    synchronized public Coupon getCoupon(long CouponID) {
        Long key = new Long(CouponID);
        if(_coupons_map != null && _coupons_map.containsKey(key)) {
            Coupon _c = (Coupon) _coupons_map.get(key);
            Date _now = new Date();
            if(_now.compareTo(_c.getDateTo()) > 0) {
                this.removeCoupon(CouponID);
                return null;
            }
            return (Coupon) _coupons_map.get(key);
        }else
            return null;
    }

    synchronized public Offer getOffer(long OfferID) {
        Long key = new Long(OfferID);
        if(_offers_map != null && _offers_map.containsKey(key)) {
            Offer _o = (Offer) _offers_map.get(key);
            Date _now = new Date();
            if(_now.compareTo(_o.getDateTo()) > 0) {
                this.removeOffer(OfferID);
                return null;
            }
            return (Offer) _offers_map.get(key);
        }else
            return null;
    }

    synchronized public ArrayList<Long> getCoupons(long ProductID) {
        Long key = new Long(ProductID);
        if(_product_to_coupons_map != null && _product_to_coupons_map.containsKey(key))
        {
            ArrayList<Long> _c_list = 
                    (ArrayList<Long>) _product_to_coupons_map.get(key);
            Iterator itr = _c_list.iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext()) {
                 Long l = (Long) itr.next();
                 if(this.getCoupon(l.longValue()) == null)
                     _c_list.remove(l.intValue());
            }
            _product_to_coupons_map.remove(key);
            _product_to_coupons_map.put(key, _c_list);
            return _c_list;
        }else
            return null;
    }

    synchronized public ArrayList<Long> getOffers(long ProductID) {
        Long key = new Long(ProductID);
        if(_product_cat_to_offers_map != null &&
                _product_cat_to_offers_map.containsKey(key)) {
            ArrayList<Long> _o_list = _product_cat_to_offers_map.get(key);
            Iterator itr = _o_list.iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext()) {
                Long l = (Long) itr.next();
                if(this.getOffer(l.longValue()) == null)
                    _o_list.remove(l.intValue());
            }
            _product_cat_to_offers_map.remove(key);
            _product_cat_to_offers_map.put(key, _o_list);
            return _o_list;
        }else
            return null;
    }

    synchronized public HashMap<Long, Coupon> getCoupons_map() {
        return _coupons_map;
    }

    synchronized public void setCoupons_map(HashMap<Long, Coupon> _coupons_map) {
        this._coupons_map = _coupons_map;
    }

    synchronized public static long getCreation_time() {
        return _creation_time;
    }

    synchronized public void cleanup_offers() {
        if(_product_cat_to_offers_map != null) {
            Set _offers_key_set = _product_cat_to_offers_map.keySet();
            Iterator itr = _offers_key_set.iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext()) {
                Long l = (Long) itr.next();
                this.getOffers(l.longValue());
            }
        }
    }

    synchronized public void cleanup_coupons() {
        if(_product_to_coupons_map != null) {
            Set _coupons_key_set = _product_to_coupons_map.keySet();
            Iterator itr = _coupons_key_set.iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext()) {
                Long l = (Long) itr.next();
                this.getCoupons(l.longValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I deploy the above application (its name is ETL_Procedures) 
to the Apache Tomcat I get the following SEVERE log entries:

```
SEVERE: The web application [/ETL_Procedures] appears to have started a thread named [maintenance-task-executor-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Oct 03, 2012 5:35:03 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoadercheckThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/ETL_Procedures] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.glassfish.gmbal.generic.OperationTracer$1] (value [org.glassfish.gmbal.generic.OperationTracer$1@4c24821]) and a value of type [java.util.ArrayList] (value [[]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Oct 03, 2012 5:35:03 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoadercheckThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/ETL_Procedures] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory$1] (value [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory$1@6f0d70f7]) and a value of type [java.util.WeakHashMap] (value [{class com.sun.xml.ws.runtime.config.TubeFactoryList=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@5b73a116, class javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.CollapsedStringAdapter=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@454da42, class com.sun.xml.ws.runtime.config.MetroConfig=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@5ec52546, class com.sun.xml.ws.runtime.config.TubeFactoryConfig=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@61124745, class java.util.ArrayList=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@770534cc, class com.sun.xml.ws.runtime.config.Tubelines=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@76cd7a1f, class javax.xml.bind.annotation.W3CDomHandler=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@2c0cc628, class com.sun.xml.ws.runtime.config.TubelineDefinition=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@7aa582af}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Oct 03, 2012 5:35:03 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoadercheckThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/ETL_Procedures] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.Coordinator$1] (value [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.Coordinator$1@826ee11]) and a value of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@33d7a245]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Oct 03, 2012 5:35:03 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/ETL_Procedures] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.glassfish.gmbal.generic.OperationTracer$1] (value [org.glassfish.gmbal.generic.OperationTracer$1@4c24821]) and a value of type [java.util.ArrayList] (value [[]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

I really do not know what causes those memory leaks. My questions are the
following:

1. Can anyone suspect what may be the issue with my web service? If the
   cause of the memory leaks is the Singleton object,
   what else can I do to meet my applications requirements and avoid memory
   leaks.
2. Is there any tool that I can use in order to monitor my threads, and
   what exactly causes these SEVERE messages?
3. If I let my application deployed for a long time, I get an
   IllegalStateException with the following message:

   ```
   INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load com.sun.xml.ws.rx.rm.localization.LocalizationMessages. The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
   java.lang.IllegalStateException at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1600) 
   at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
   at com.sun.xml.ws.rx.rm.runtime.sequence.SequenceMaintenanceTask.run(SequenceMaintenanceTask.java:81)
   at com.sun.xml.ws.commons.DelayedTaskManager$Worker.run(DelayedTaskManager.java:91)
   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
   ```

How can I see the whole call path that causes this Exception?

Thank you for your time and I am really sorry for the long message.

Comment: If you suspect a memory leak, I suggest you use a memory profiler on your application. Its usually more useful than guessing what the problem might be.

Comment: I am learning how to profile it right now :-) . Thank you for your interest and your quick answer. Did you spot anything wrong with my classes implementation? I know that this is a general question, but before I jump into the details, opinions from experienced developers are more than welcome.

Comment: Many thing could be improved IMHO, but nothing which could be causing a bug.  Its quite likely your issue isn't in this code at all which is why you need a profiler to help you point it.

Comment: @popanik Have you read this article? http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/MemoryLeakProtection

Comment: @user1516873 Yes, and to be honest, I could not see in which of the cases my web application belongs to. Right now I am trying to learn the Netbeans profiler in order to locate the Memory Leaks. However, I can not understand if the issue is either a bug in my code, or a bug in the framework.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Can you please post some of the improvements you referred. Any indication or advice is welcome :-).

Comment: I would use an enum Singleton as its is much simpler, I use camelCase for fields and avoid using `_` in class or field names (except constants), I use interfaces for variable types instead of concrete classes. I make fields final where possible. I use auto-boxing instead of `new Long(long)` as its shorter, easier to read and can be faster.

Comment: I use `long` for Date as it can be more efficient, but this may not be as clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you got `java.lang.IllegalStateException` when your application was redeployed, but failed to undeploy, and some old process still run. Maybe when you redeploy application some threads was waiting while other thread leave `synchronization` block. Maybe it is some scheduled process, do you have any? Difficult to say what it was.

I can suggest you to register listener in web.xml and in `contextDestroyed()` method clean up all resources. And run some memory analyzing tool, for example, [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)

Comment: Can you please post a link with guidelines for registering listeners in web.xml? It would be very helpful. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: So, by using a context listener, I can use my Singleton object as a global object for all my web service calls? Moreover, it will be created when my web application starts, and it will be destroyed when my web application stops? Sorry for asking so many questions, but as you can see I am still learning :-).

Comment: Yes, you can. Just make sure your listener will initialized _before_ WebService listener. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html And maybe class ConcurrentHashMap http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html will be usefull. It helps you avoid `synchronized` keyword on whole methods.

Comment: OK, thank you. I used to use ConcurrentHashMap instead of HashMap, but after a little search I conducted, It is said that in case someone uses Iterators, a ConcurrentHashMap object is not secure against Critical Section problems.

Comment: Ok, you know your code better :) But problem is, when you use `synchronized` on whole methods, it can work fast for one - two users, but when many simultianeusly users appears, perfomance degrade very quickly. And all benefits of using fast in-memory cach disappears.

Comment: One final question. How am I going to get the initial Context from the ETL_WS constructor. I see that the ContextListener in the tutorial you referenced, takes as parameters events. Which are those events, and how am I going to use the ContextListener class in my code? Thank you

Comment: Usually ServletContext uses in http servlet methods `doGet()` and `doPost()`, but i think you can inject it in your webservice class as `@Resource private WebServiceContext context;` I'm not sure about this, but ws request run over http request, so i don't see why it shouldn't work.